# Appending only first part of textfile info into array

Tags: python, arrays, text

I am trying to read a large file of data into an array on python then do some computing on it. I am seperating each line of a textfile then reading each line into an array using the .append() function.

However I do not want the entire line. This is what the textfile contains per line.

```
1000661813$10006618$1$PS$LIPITOR$ATORVASTATIN CALCIUM$1$$UNK$$$U$$$$020702$$$FILM-COATED TABLET$
```

I only want the first bit "1000661813". The $ seperates the different parts of the info. Each line may differ in the length of that first number. Is there any way I can read each line into an array and make it only that first number?

Not sure where to start

```
fileDrug19Q2 = open('DRUG19Q2.txt')

arrayDrug19Q2 = list()

for line in fileDrug19Q2:
    arrayDrug19Q2.append(line)
```

Comment: You mean the number that you want to get is always the first in the line and separated by the first `$`?

Comment: The easiest option would be `text.split('$')[0]`. Otherwise, check out regular expressions: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression

Answer (score 1):

you can try split function before appending to list like this:

```
 for line in fileDrug:
   arrayDrug19Q2.append(line.split("$")[0])
```

Comment: I do not know about the difference in performance, but `line.partition('$')[0]` is an alternative. It *may* be faster as it stops after the fist occurrence of the string. Although, using `line.split('$', 1)` is also an option for this.